# Asp.Net Identity Log-in After Timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using Identity authentication in my Asp.Net MVC project.

When a user, **User A**, whose session has timed-out makes a request of the server, the server returns the log-in page along with a return url which is the url **User A** was asking for. This way, when **User A** re-authenticates, s/he is redirected to that initial request.

Leaving things as they are, if, rather than **User A** re-authenticating, some **User B** authenticates instead, s/he will be directed to **User A**'s last request rather than to the default home page.

How can I tell the server to redirect to the return url only if the current user is the same as the one who had timed out?

Answer (score 0):

The server is not going to know if the timed out session is the same user as the new session, (the old session is gone, after all) so you can't do this based on that information alone.

Some alternatives:

1. You could, however, attempt to parse the ReturnUrl parameter in the
   action that accepts your login credentials, and after
   authenticating, write your own business logic to determine if the
   URL being requested belongs to the newly authenticated account, and
   redirect accordingly.
2. You may consider getting rid of the ReturnUrl feature altogether,
   and just redirect everyone to the same landing page after logging
   in, regardless of what link was clicked.
3. Another alternative would be a client script that preempts
   unauthenticated requests to restricted resources by simply
   navigating the page to the login page automatically after a set
   timeout. Similar to what your bank probably does if you leave your
   account page open past the timeout.

Comment: I don't know enough about how Identity works, but, in theory, even if a request provides an expired cookie, the server should still be able to see to whom that cookie was provided and send that information back together with the return url. This way, after authentication the server can check whether the current user is the same as the previous user.

Comment: 1. Parsing the url parameter is useless for me: the requested resources are not user-specific.

Comment: #3 doesn't give me much more advantage over #2. Going with #2 for now.